# css animation to set height of div

Tags: css

i am wondering if it is possible to set the height of a div with css animation.
I have a div that when you hover over it opens up but i want it to stay that height not shrink back to the original height.
Is this possible?
it needs to be done in pure css not javascript as its a website for college

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery.  CSS3 is not supported in all browsers.  However, it is possible to use CSS3 to achieve this.

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    height:20px;/* initial height */
    width:100px;
    background:#aaa;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s linear; /* you can replace 'height' with the attribute you are changing (eg: color, width...)*/
    -moz-transition: height .4s linear;
    -o-transition: height .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: height .4s linear;
    transition: height .4s linear;
}

#myDiv:hover {
    height:100px; /* desired height */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see that you needed it to stay that height.  In order to do that, you would need to use something like onmouseout (or another event listener), which in the end would use Javascript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

### HTML:

```
<div class="divAnimate" onmouseout="this.className='setHeight'">Div Height Animation</div>​
```

### CSS:

```
.divAnimate {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.divAnimate:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
.setHeight {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/hj5Sq/)**

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, but it's supported better than CSS3, and it's quite helpful. :)

Comment: @Caleb: If, **and only if**, the browser does not support CSS3 (can be detected with a feature detector), ***only then*** should you use a jQuery fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with just CSS3, but will only work in Safari/Chrome and recent versions of Opera, Mozilla Firefox, and IE10 as you need CSS3 animation keyframes to preserve the end-state of the transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/rPc88/3/